# How to choose a llm model

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model, llama

Iam new to LLM's. I have a question on how to choose a llm model. My requirement is I want to create a LLM model that can answer oceanography based questions. I want to train the model daily with the ocean state forecast data like potential fishing zones information.

If the user asks for nearest potential fishing zone based on his location, model has to return the coordinates of nearest fishing zone. This is one of the usecase we want to try.

Should we go with a pretrained model like llama2 7b model or any other models that you can suggest.

I read that models like llama2 7b require atleast 28GB GPU but we do have a GPU HPC with 12GB RAM. how can we train these kind of large models for evaluation with less RAM.

I am still evaluating didn't try anything

Comment: Just to make clear. You don't expect it to predict where fish can be found, right?